# Consider $G$ is a connected graph. For any vertex $v$ in $G$, prove that there exists a matching for which $v$ is saturated.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I couldn't think of any connected graphs where the property didn't hold, so assume it is true. However, I couldn't think of a formal proof. I tried doing this:

Case I: If $G$ has an even number of vertices, then the maximum matching is a perfect matching, so the property holds.

Case II: If $G$ has an odd number of vertices, then there is no perfect matching, so there must be a vertex not saturated by the maximum matching.... This is the part I am stuck in, I cannot think of a way I can show that it is possible to saturate each vertex by different maximum matchings. How do I show that a graph can have multiple maximum matchings?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for modified question:

This is trivial true. For each vertex just take a maximal matchings that contains that vertex. You don't need even connectivety, just every vertex should have degree at least 1.

---

No, take graph: $u-v-w$ then maximal we have only 2 maximal matchings:

- matching is $u-v$ and $w$ is not saturated
- matching is $v-w$ and $u$ is not saturated.

Even if graph has even vertices it does not hold. Take a graph with 4 vertices $a,b,c, d$ and edges $a-d$, $b-d$ and $c-d$. In this case only $d$ and one of $a,b,c$ are saturated while other two not, for any maximal matching.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this, what the question is trying to say that it is possible that taking any particular vertex, it is possible for it to be a part of a certain maximum matching.

Comment: But that is trivialy true and complitely different from the question.

Comment: Don't we need to show that there are more than one maximum matchings first?

Comment: But I did that. In first case you have 2 max. matchings and 1 vertex stay unsaturated in each case. In second example there are 3 max. matchings and in each case 2 vertices are not saturated.

Comment: Yes, for example in your first example $w$ is unsaturated for the matching $u-v$, but is is possible to saturate is using the matching $v-w$. So, there exists a matching for which $w$ is saturated. Now how can we show that this is possible for any vertex in a connected graph $G$. I may need to reword the question a bit. EDIT: question has been reworded to hopefully avoid ambiguity.